# i type code for react-datepicker with redux forms

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-datepicker

i type code for react-datepicker with redux forms and it works but when i choose the date all thing in the page disapper and get console error of Invalid time value enter code here

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import moment from "moment";

const DateInput = ({
  input: { value, onChange, ...restInput },
  width,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
      <DatePicker
        {...rest}
        placeholderText={placeholder}
        selected={value ? moment(value) : value}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...restInput}
      />
      {touched && error && (
        <Label basic color="red">
          {error}
        </Label>
      )}
    </Form.Field>
  );
};

export default DateInput;

<Field
    name="date"
    type="text"
    component={DateInput}
    dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    showTimeSelect
    placeholder="Date and time of event"
/>
```